# Better way to use try except block

Tags: python, try-except

I have a requirement to execute multiple Python statements and few of them might fail during execution, even after failing I want the rest of them to be executed.

Currently, I am doing:

```
try:
    wx.StaticBox.Destroy()
    wx.CheckBox.Disable()
    wx.RadioButton.Enable()
except:
    pass
```

If any one of the statements fails, `except` will get executed and program exits. But what I need is even though it is failed it should run all three statements.

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: How can it possibly run all 3 if any one of them can't run because it failed?

Comment: 1. Don't use bare `except`, *at the very least* use `except Exception`. 2. If these statements should be executed (or not) independently, **put them in separate `try` blocks!**

Comment: @TimCastelijns I guess he means they should all be attempted.

Comment: Are each of the statements (in your actual code) method calls?

Answer (score 6):

Use a `for` loop over the methods you wish to call, eg:

```
for f in (wx.StaticBox.Destroy, wx.CheckBox.Disable, wx.RadioButton.Enable):
    try:
        f()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Note that we're using `except Exception` here - that's generally much more likely what you want than a bare except.

Answer (score 4):

If an exception occurs during a `try` block, the rest of the block is skipped. You should use three separate `try` clauses for your three separate statements.

Added in response to comment:

Since you apparently want to handle many statements, you could use a wrapper method to check for exceptions:

```
def mytry(functionname):
    try:
        functionname()
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Then call the method with the name of your function as input:

```
mytry(wx.StaticBox.Destroy)
```

Comment: I just took an example as 3 statements. In real time i have more than 12 statements. 12 try except block in program wouldn't look good.

Comment: @Arunkumar In that case, use a wrapper method. See my edit, which I will make in a second.

Comment: @Arunkumar then you need *"more than 12"* blocks, or to refactor into a loop. You may be able to use [`contextlib.suppress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress) to neaten the code if you're using Python 3.4.

Comment: `mytry` seems a bit limited; at the very least, allow it to take the errors to suppress as an argument (the default can still be `Exception`).

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 16712, in __getattr__
    raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the TextCtrl object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed.

Comment: In the First Call TextControl was destroyed ... In Second function call TextCtrl is being Cleared but its allready deleted ... so it should come to except block ... but its not working so.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend creating a context manager class that suppress any exception and the exceptions to be logged.

Please look at the code below. Would encourage any improvement to it.

```
import sys
class catch_exception:
    def __init__(self, raising=True):
        self.raising = raising

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if issubclass(type, Exception):
            self.raising = False

        print ("Type: ", type, " Log me to error log file")
        return not self.raising



def staticBox_destroy():
    print("staticBox_destroy")
    raise TypeError("Passing through")

def checkbox_disable():
    print("checkbox_disable")
    raise ValueError("Passing through")

def radioButton_enable():
    print("radioButton_enable")
    raise ValueError("Passing through")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with catch_exception() as cm:
        staticBox_destroy()
    with catch_exception() as cm:
        checkbox_disable()
    with catch_exception() as cm:
        radioButton_enable()
```

Comment: Oh... **wow**. Please immediately read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, I'm not even touching that.

Comment: I have fixed the formatting. Sorry, using stack for the first time. Thanks for the link.